# Poll is not saving

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I am building a PollApp and I am stuck on a Problem..

I build a `poll add` feature for add `images` in the poll . BUT `images` are not adding in the `Poll`.

When i select images in field then save it redirect to the same page and saying `"This field is required"`.

models.py

```
class ImageChoice(models.Model):
    image_poll = models.ForeignKey(ImagePoll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_image = models.FileField()
```

views.py

```
def polls_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImagePollAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            poll = form.save(commit=False)
            poll.owner = request.user
            poll.save()
            new_choice1 = ImageChoice(poll=poll, image=form.cleaned_data['choice1']).save()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'add_poll.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class ImagePollAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    choice1 = forms.FileField()


    class Meta:
        model = ImagePoll
        fields = ['choice1']
```

When i try to upload `images` in each field then click to `save` then it is not uploading.

I also tried by adding **request.FILES** in `form = ImagePollAddForm(request.POST)` BUT it is showing `ImageChoice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'poll'` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use invalid field name, your model has **image_poll** field but not poll. And your model does not have image field but **choice_image**

```
ImageChoice(image_poll=poll, choice_image=form.cleaned_data['choice1']).save()
```

Comment: It is still NOT `saving` the poll after renaming . AND when i user **request.FILES** then it is saying `ImageChoice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image'`.

Comment: @GOO Check I edited my answer. Your error message literally tells you what is wrong.